# Show only some elements of a list in a view using a custom adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this Kotlin class:

```
class Food (name: String, kindOfFood: String) {
    var name: String = ""
    var KinOfFood: String = ""

    init {
        this.name = name
        this.kindOfFood = kindOfFood
    }
}
```

To which I add elements in another class like this:

```
val food: ArrayList<Food> = ArrayList()
    food.add(Food("My Dish", "pizza"))
    food.add(Food("My Dish 02", "salad))
```

When trying to display the elements on a view, i use something like this:

```
fun onCreate(){
    buttonSalad.setOnClickListener {
        intentOpc("salad")
    }
}

private fun intentOpc(foodType: String) {
    val intent = Intent(this, MenuList::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("FOODNAME", fodType)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

What I want to do is to display only the food with the same category (pizza, salad, pasta) as `FOODNAME` but my custom adapter shows all the dishes in the list instead.
this is my custom adapter:

```
class MenuAdapter(var context: Context, items: ArrayList<Platillo>): BaseAdapter() {
    var items: ArrayList<Food>? = null

    init {
        this.items = items

    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return items?.count()!!
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return items?.get(position)!!
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var holder: ViewHolder? = null
        var myView: View? = convertView

        if (myView == null){
            myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_menu_adapter, null)
            holder = ViewHolder(myView)
            myView.tag = holder
        } else
            holder = myView.tag as ViewHolder

        val item = getItem(position) as Food
        holder.name?.text = item.name
        holder.price?.text = item.price.toString()

        return myView!!
    }

    private class ViewHolder(myView: View) {
        var name: TextView? = null
        var price: TextView? = null

        init {
            name = myView.findViewById(R.id.name)
            price = myView.findViewById(R.id.price)
        }
    }
}
```

[I want this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOSOn.jpg)

[Instead got this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJuRN.png)

Where should I modify my code?

Comment: I don't see anywhere you've tried to filter in your adapter? Or are you asking us to do it for you?

Comment: @HenryTwist I tried filtering and got [this](https://imgur.com/a/rkJBjAj), but deleted the lines that did that and now I don’t remember where they were written inside the adapter.

Comment: filter the array before passing it to your adapter? `items.filter { it.KinOfFood.equals("yourFoodNameFromIntent") }`